# Fetch data from the database using ajax and assign data to variable

Tags: php, ajax

I had tried to fetch data from database and assign into a variable but it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({   
          type  : 'ajax',
                url   : 'display.php',
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',     
                  
          success: function(response){    
            var i;
           //alert(response[0].fake_msg);
                //  for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
          
           var Fake = [alert("'<div>" +response[0].fake_msg+"</div>',")];
          
        //  }
           
          }
       
      });
});
```

Comment: What is there in display.php?

Comment: “Not working” isn’t a useful description of the problem. What behaviour do you expect? What behaviour do you get? What errors are reported on the browser’s developer tools?

Comment: in display.php data is coming from the database

Answer (score 0):

Shoudn't your "type" should be "GET" or "POST"?

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

In F12 you can open network tab and see what your response is.

Comment: help me how to assign var in ajax

Comment: Can you be more specific where you want to assign it? When you get response from 'display.php'?

success: function(response){    
            console.log(response);
           // You will see what you get from display.php.
           // if you get your required data, you can assign it just like in js.
          }

Answer (score 0):

Run this `$.get('display.php', data => console.log('done', data));` and past here console result, and network page.